# calling variable inside previous block of IF statement in another block

Tags: php, if-statement

i have this scenero, i have if statement like below, however i want to call the variable set in one block of IF statement and use it in another block of IF statement. Kindly look at the scenero in the code below

```
  if($month == '01')
{

        $expected_closing_stock_book_balance_dec =  getParameters($outlet_id, $getmonth, $getyear,'expected closing stock book balance');



}
  if($month == '02')
{
       $expected_closing_stock_book_balance_jan  = $expected_closing_stock_book_balance_dec + $total_liter_received ;

}
  if($month == '03')
{
       $expected_closing_stock_book_balance_feb  = $expected_closing_stock_book_balance_jan + $total_liter_received ;

}
```

Comment: create a global variable

Comment: I suggest you find a basic PHP tutorial. Lots of little things are wrong in your code.

Comment: yes i know, this is just a sample scenero, not exactly my code. I just want to know how to access variables in previous block of IF statement in thext block

Comment: Why not just get the month number and * 1000?

Comment: thanks this is close, in my implentation im using if($month == '01')   and goto 01 doesnt seems to work.     01; doesnt work too, please advice

Comment: Can you show your actual code. na dont use gotos :s like i said why not just * by 1000? as thats all your code is doing.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, i have edited my code

Comment: Whats `getParameters` do? If it gets the current value use that then just +  `$total_liter_received` as it wont hold state anyway.

Comment: getParameters  its a function which is outside if statement and working

Comment: Im not sure why you dont just do.. https://3v4l.org/brcuF - as `$total_liter_received` is not changing.

Comment: this wont work because i want to be able to echo for month 01,02,03-----12 on same page and each month value will be carried to the next month value. maybe my logic is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't forsee this working.

You cannot get the variable from the previous month because the if statement ISNT met.  IF month == 02, then the month is NOT 01.  So it won't even call the 01 if statement.

You can run the command for the previous month in the current month.  for example:

```
 if($month == '02')
{
$expected_closing_stock_book_balance_dec =  getParameters($outlet_id, $getmonth, $getyear,'expected closing stock book balance');
$expected_closing_stock_book_balance_jan  = $expected_closing_stock_book_balance_dec + $total_liter_received ;
}
```

and repeat that for each additional month.  To get the variables you need in each if statement.

**But the code will be redundent.  You will have to enter it multiple times which makes editing the code a pain.**

**I would create a function for each statement.  Put it at the top of the file.  Inside each if statement, call the functions needed to get the results INSIDE each if statement.**

---

### EDIT

Its hard to write a function for something that I don't completely understand.  So I'm going to attempt to do this; however, it isnt tested because I have no clue where you are setting variables, how you are calling them, or how your project is setup.  This is just for example purposes.

```
function lastdecember() { $lastdecember = getParameters($outlet_id, $getmonth, $getyear,'expected closing stock book balance'); }
function january() { $january = ...january balance...; }
function february() { $february = ...february balance...; }
function march() { $march = ...march balance...; }
function total_liter_received() { $total_liter_received = ....; }



if($month == '01') {  
$expected_closing_stock_book_balance_dec = lastdecember(); 
}

if($month == '02') {
$expected_closing_stock_book_balance_jan  = lastdember() + total_liter_received()
}

if($month == '03') {
$expected_closing_stock_book_balance_feb  = january() + total_liter_received();
}
```

and you can echo or set variables however you need.  But you need to set each of the january, feb, march, etc. main variables in functions and then for each month, call the function needed for whichever month you need.

Comment: ok, can you give a scenero for jan to dec, like for jan, echo dec, for feb, echo jan + something, for march echo feb + something.......and continue like that

Comment: added an edit to code.  Again, this is just a quick code example based on less than a minute of understanding your entire project.  Modify as needed...test...test again...test again.

Comment: you can call a function from within another function as well.  You can set `$january` to be `$january = december() + total_litter_received();` inside january's function.  But again,  I don't know how you are fully setting your variables and calling them in the full scope of your project

Comment: woow, i am sure this clue will work, im coming back to give a feedback. thans

Comment: I hope this works well for you.  I think it will.  Make sure to accept the answer if it does!  Good luck!

Comment: Did you figure it out?